# Multiple circles overlap on the map

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, openstreetmap

I use Leaflet for showing coverage map.
I create many circles in nearby location by radius and opacity.
Circles are overlap and filled color is very bold.
How can prevent overlap and all color should be same?

[image: Leaflet overlap]

I create many circles in nearby location by radius and opacity.
Circles are overlap and filled color is very bold.
How can prevent overlap and all color should be same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying each individual location you could use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to group them:

[image: Leaflet.markercluster example]